# JavaScript and JSON, how to parse?

Tags: javascript, json, zendesk

Ok, so I am having a lot of trouble creating an app which works with Zendesk. Basically what I need to do is search all tickets in the database and count how many there are for each end-user. The end-user is a text field within each ticket.

So here is where I am:

'/api/v2/tickets.json' - this is a list of all tickets in JSON format
  - this gets put into a variable 'tickets' which I use after
  - I thought 'tickets' would be an array but now I don't think it is, so how can itterate through it?

NOW - how can I access the values in this tickets file? For example, how can I access the 'End-User' value with JavaScript?

I have looked through Zendesk's documentation for their API and can't find anything useful for getting this to work and their forums are somewhat dead. Hopefully you guys can help me out since I am a total beginner at JavaScript.

Ok here is an example of a JSON record:

```
{"tickets":[{"url":"https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/1.json","id":1,"external_id":null,"via":{"channel":"web","source":{"from":{},"to":{},"rel":null}},"created_at":"2012-10-01T16:06:33Z","updated_at":"2012-10-05T19:21:55Z","type":"incident","subject":"This is a sample ticket requested and submitted by you","description":"This is the first comment. Feel free to delete this sample ticket.","priority":"high","status":"closed","recipient":null,"requester_id":270249903,"submitter_id":270249903,"assignee_id":270249903,"organization_id":22242373,"group_id":20363013,"collaborator_ids":[],"forum_topic_id":null,"problem_id":null,"has_incidents":false,"due_at":null,"tags":["sample","zendesk"],"fields":[{"id":21717236,"value":"10/4/2012"}],"custom_fields":[{"id":21717236,"value":"10/4/2012"}],"satisfaction_rating":null},{"url":"https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/2.json","id":2,"external_id":null,"via":{"channel":"email","source":{"from":{"address":"noreply@zendesk.com","name":"Zendesk"},"to":{"address":"support@company.zendesk.com","name":"Binary Stream Helpdesk"},"rel":null}},"created_at":"2012-10-01T16:33:58Z","updated_at":"2012-10-05T17:09:37Z","type":null,"subject":"Tudor Hofnar, here is the test ticket you requested","description":"        Hello! This is a Zendesk ticket. We are going to go through the basic support ticket operation in Zendesk.\n\n        If you are in your email reading this, please click on the link in the header that starts with Ticket #.\n\n        If you are in your Zendesk reading this, you will see the ticket number, the customer who sent this ticket in, and drop down menus that allow you to set things like status and priority. You'll also notice a blank text box below this comment. That is for you to respond. Let's do that:\n\n        1. Write: \"Thanks for this information, please tell me more.\"\n        2. Change the drop-down field labeled Status to \"Pending\"\n\n        If you follow these instructions, you'll get an email response back from us shortly.  You can also always see ticket updates by going back into your unsolved ticket view (click view in the top menu bar).\n","priority":null,"status":"closed","recipient":null,"requester_id":270263553,"submitter_id":270263553,"assignee_id":270249903,"organization_id":null,"group_id":20363013,"collaborator_ids":[],"forum_topic_id":null,"problem_id":null,"has_incidents":false,"due_at":null,"tags":[],"fields":[{"id":21717236,"value":"10/4/2012"}],"custom_fields":[{"id":21717236,"value":"10/4/2012"}],"satisfaction_rating":null},{"url":"https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/3.json","id":3,"external_id":null,"via":{"channel":"email","source":{"from":{"address":"tudor@binarystream.com","name":"Tudor Hofnar"},"to":{"address":"support@company.zendesk.com","name":"Binary Stream Helpdesk"},"rel":null}},"created_at":"2012-10-01T17:08:37Z","updated_at":"2012-10-05T18:15:01Z","type":null,"subject":"test","description":"test\n\nTudor Hofnar","priority":null,"status":"closed","recipient":"support@company.zendesk.com","requester_id":270249903,"submitter_id":270249903,"assignee_id":270249903,"organization_id":22242373,"group_id":20363013,"collaborator_ids":[],"forum_topic_id":null,"problem_id":null,"has_incidents":false,"due_at":null,"tags":[],"fields":[{"id":21717236,"value":"10/4/2012"}],"custom_fields":[{"id":21717236,"value":"10/4/2012"}],"satisfaction_rating":null},{"url":"https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/5.json","id":5,"external_id":null,"via":{"channel":"web","source":{"from":{},"to":{},"rel":null}},"created_at":"2012-10-01T20:26:34Z","updated_at":"2012-10-06T22:39:09Z","type":"incident","subject":"Window for adding account not opening","description":"The add account window is not opening and it is causing a lot of trouble for our team etc....","priority":"normal","status":"closed","recipient":null,"requester_id":271853958,"submitter_id":271853958,"assignee_id":270249903,"organization_id":22284363,"group_id":20363013,"collaborator_ids":[],"forum_topic_id":null,"problem_id":null,"has_incidents":false,"due_at":null,"tags":["2_2_2","4","ared","end_user_1","var_2"],"fields":[{"id":21704983,"value":"1"},{"id":21708732,"value":"tried this"},{"id":21708742,"value":"1"},{"id":21713331,"value":"10/2/2012"},{"id":21717086,"value":"ared"},{"id":21717236,"value":"10/4/2012"},{"id":21717357,"value":"2_2_2"}],"custom_fields":[{"id":21704983,"value":"1"},{"id":21708732,"value":"tried this"},{"id":21708742,"value":"1"},{"id":21713331,"value":"10/2/2012"},{"id":21717086,"value":"ared"},{"id":21717236,"value":"10/4/2012"},{"id":21717357,"value":"2_2_2"}],"satisfaction_rating":null},{"url":"https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/6.json","id":6,"external_id":null,"via":{"channel":"web","source":{"from":{},"to":{},"rel":null}},"created_at":"2012-10-02T21:14:59Z","updated_at":"2012-10-09T18:22:04Z","type":"incident","subject":"Test Ticket","description":"this is a test ticket","priority":"normal","status":"closed","recipient":null,"requester_id":271853958,"submitter_id":271853958,"assignee_id":270249903,"organization_id":22284363,"group_id":20363013,"collaborator_ids":[],"forum_topic_id":null,"problem_id":null,"has_incidents":false,"due_at":null,"tags":["2_2_2","arcb","end_user_1","var_2"],"fields":[{"id":21704983,"value":"1"},{"id":21708732,"value":"tried this"},{"id":21708742,"value":"1"},{"id":21713331,"value":"10/2/2012"},{"id":21717086,"value":"arcb"},{"id":21717236,"value":"10/2/2012"},{"id":21717357,"value":""},{"id":21728942,"value":null},{"id":21732321,"value":"Test End-User"}],"custom_fields":[{"id":21704983,"value":"1"},{"id":21708732,"value":"tried this"},{"id":21708742,"value":"1"},{"id":21713331,"value":"10/2/2012"},{"id":21717086,"value":"arcb"},{"id":21717236,"value":"10/2/2012"},{"id":21717357,"value":""},{"id":21728942,"value":null},{"id":21732321,"value":"Test End-User"}],"satisfaction_rating":null},{"url":"https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/7.json","id":7,"external_id":null,"via":{"channel":"web","source":{"from":{},"to":{},"rel":null}},"created_at":"2012-10-09T20:09:50Z","updated_at":"2012-10-11T18:19:42Z","type":"question","subject":"Testing bookmarks","description":"this is a bookmark test\n","priority":"normal","status":"open","recipient":null,"requester_id":270249903,"submitter_id":270249903,"assignee_id":270249903,"organization_id":22242373,"group_id":20363013,"collaborator_ids":[],"forum_topic_id":null,"problem_id":null,"has_incidents":false,"due_at":null,"tags":["2010","psm"],"fields":[{"id":21704983,"value":"0"},{"id":21708732,"value":null},{"id":21708742,"value":"1"},{"id":21713331,"value":"10/9/2012"},{"id":21717086,"value":"psm"},{"id":21717236,"value":"10/31/2012"},{"id":21717357,"value":"2010"},{"id":21728942,"value":"Var 1"},{"id":21732321,"value":"End User 2"}],"custom_fields":[{"id":21704983,"value":"0"},{"id":21708732,"value":null},{"id":21708742,"value":"1"},{"id":21713331,"value":"10/9/2012"},{"id":21717086,"value":"psm"},{"id":21717236,"value":"10/31/2012"},{"id":21717357,"value":"2010"},{"id":21728942,"value":"Var 1"},{"id":21732321,"value":"End User 2"}],"satisfaction_rating":null}],"next_page":null,"previous_page":null,"count":6}
```

*not sure how to format this code...*

Now this is my JS code, I know its wrong what I am trying to do with 'tickets' but I have no idea how to access it...

```
(function() {

  return {
    // Here we define AJAX calls
    requests: {
      fetchTickets: function() {
        return {
          url: '/api/v2/tickets.json',
          type: 'GET'
        };
      }
    },
    // Here we define events such as a user clicking on something
    events: {
      'app.activated': 'requestTickets',

      'fetchTickets.always': function(data) {
        this.countEndUserTickets((data || {}).tickets);
      }
    },
    // Below this point, you're free to define your own functions used by the app   
    requestTickets: function() {
      this.ajax('fetchTickets');
    },

    countEndUserTickets: function(tickets) {
      var endUser = this.ticket().customField("End-User"); //this will get the end-user of the current ticket that is open in Zendesk
      var ticketCounter = 0;

      //this is where I have no idea how to access the 'tickets' array or whatever it is
      for (var i = 0; i <= tickets.length; i++) {
        if (tickets[i].customField("End-User") == endUser){
          ticketCounter = ticketCounter + 1;
        }
      }

      alert(endUser);

      this.switchTo('list', {
        ticketCounter: this.ticketCounter
      });
    }
  };  
}());
```

Comment: _I thought 'tickets' would be an array but now I don't think it is_ What does the json look like for the response that gives you multiple tickets?

Comment: In the JSON you provided, what field are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the 'End-User' field which is a custom field...it seems like Zendesk does not have the actual name in the JSON just the ID which is 21732321

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tepbd/1/ returns in the console (hit F12 in Chrome to see it) log output the object that includes that field.  I cannot get the getJSON() mentioned below to work yet. @Gabirel Florit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [their documentation](http://www.zendesk.com/support/api/rest-introduction), Zendesk supports JSONP:

> you can specify a callback by appending “?callback=your_call_back_function” to the GET URL

So, you can change your url to `'/api/v2/tickets.json?callback=fetchTicketsCallback'` and `fetchTicketsCallback` will be called, passing in a fully-parsed JavaScript object.

**Edit:** Actually, according to [this documentation](http://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/example.html) (which looks an awful lot like the code you posted), Zendesk ajax handlers receive fully parsed JavaScript objects, not raw JSON strings.  So, there should be no reason to change the url at all.  Just access the members via standard dot or square bracket notation.  So, to get the value of the field with an `id` of `21732321`:

```
ticket.fields.filter(function(field) {
    return field.id == 21732321;
})[0].value;
```

It looks like you want:

```
function countTickets(user) {
    var count = 0;
    response.tickets.forEach(function(ticket) {
        var filteredFields = ticket.fields.filter(function(field) {
            return field.id == 21732321;
        });
        if (filteredFields.length > 0 && filteredFields[0].value == user) {
            count++;
        }
    });
    return count;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/azRJM/

Comment: Ok, so since its a fully parsed JavaScript object how can I index a specific ticket within the JSON file. Say there are 10 ticket records and I want the 6th one. I would do this using tickets[6] in other programming language but how does it work with JSON?

Comment: @TudorHofnar - it's not JSON, it's JavaScript.  JSON is a data serialization format and is always a string.  You have a JavaScript object (possibly deserialized from JSON).  In JavaScript, to get an element of an Array, you use square bracket notation, passing in the index of the desired element.  Eg, for the 6th element: `tickets[5]` (JavaScript indeces are 0-based, so the 6th element is at index 5).

Comment: I tried doing something like this var test = tickets[4].status(); to get the status of the 5th ticket and I get nothing returned...Am I missing something?

Comment: @TudorHofnar - Using parens indicates you are calling a method.  JavaScript objects parsed from JSON never contain methods (unless they are extended after being parsed).  Omit the parens to access the value of a property.

Comment: Ah yes! My bad, I used the parens because there is another way to get the status but that is for the current open ticket like this var status = this.ticket().status(); so I confused myself! Thanks! I will try to get the whole thing working now

Comment: I just saw your edited post above...and I'm trying to wrap my head around it. So basically lets say I know the end user that I need to see the amount of tickets for, and then all I need is to search though the JSON to find how many tickets belong to that user. For example, there is a text field and I enter 'End-User 1' then this method runs and returns how many tickets 'End-User 1' has. I'm trying to understand your method but am confused at var userField...also the [0] at the end of that statement..

Comment: Also I don't seem to be able to use ticket.fields.filter, error is thrown because I am using 'ticket', 'ticket' is not defined. This is from Zendesk.

Comment: Ok figured it out I think, ticket needs to be ticket[i] where i is an index. But since you use foreach, I don't have an index. Should I just create another variable to use within the foreach statement and increment it?

Comment: @TudorHofnar - All I can do is guess, because the JSON sample you posted doesn't contain the members you are talking about, such as `tickets`.  Can you update the JSON in your question to be more complete?

Comment: @TudorHofnar - I updated my answer with some comments in the code that should help to clarify what is going on in there.

Comment: Alright, I pasted my entire JSON, it has 6 tickets. Sorry about the formatting, but that is what I am working with to try and count the number of tickets/end user. I don't want to receive all end users counts at once. I just want one, for example a hard coded one is fine, such as "End-User 1".

Comment: @TudorHofnar - I updated my example and posted a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/azRJM/) based on the response you provided.

Comment: Thank you!!! That makes sense, and it works fine in the jsFiddle but I can't seem to get this working in my app. For now I am simply trying to use an alert to see if the value returned is correct. I tried the value in the jsFiddle and it returns 1 (Test End-User) now in my app, the message box does not pop up...this is how I am creating it alert(count); Is this correct?

Comment: Also, since my 'response' is coming in as 'tickets' I can just remove 'response' from the first row? I tried doing tickets.tickets.forEach but that did not work either. tickets.tickets kind of makes sense since my tickets is equal to your response...but I still can't get any values in the alert.

Comment: Nevermind! I got it working, problem on my part with the alert! Thanks you so much for your help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery makes it really easy with jQuery.parseJSON
Here's a simple example: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: Why cannot you just set the well-formed JSON object to a var.  Doesn't it result in an object with keys: values?  I tried it in jsfiddle on Chrome and it did - is there some kind of cross-browser compatibility problem?  Here is my jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/tepbd/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var json = '{ "url":"https://test.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/6.json", "id":6, "external_id":null, "via":{ "channel":"web", "source":{ "from":{}, "to":{}, "rel":null } }, "created_at":"2012-10-02T21:14:59Z", "updated_at":"2012-10-09T18:22:04Z", "type":"incident", "subject":"Test Ticket", "description":"this is a test ticket", "priority":"normal", "status":"closed", "recipient":null, "requester_id":271853958, "submitter_id":271853958, "assignee_id":270249903, "organization_id":22284363, "group_id":20363013, "collaborator_ids":[], "forum_topic_id":null, "problem_id":null, "has_incidents":false, "due_at":null, "tags":["2_2_2","arcb","end_user_1","var_2"], "fields":[ {"id":21704983,"value":"1"}, {"id":21708732,"value":"tried this"}, {"id":21708742,"value":"1"}, {"id":21713331,"value":"10/2/2012"}, {"id":21717086,"value":"arcb"}, {"id":21717236,"value":"10/2/2012"}, {"id":21717357,"value":""}, {"id":21728942,"value":null}, {"id":21732321,"value":"Test End-User"}], "custom_fields":[{"id":21704983,"value":"1"}, {"id":21708732,"value":"tried this"}, {"id":21708742,"value":"1"}, {"id":21713331,"value":"10/2/2012"}, {"id":21717086,"value":"arcb"}, {"id":21717236,"value":"10/2/2012"}, {"id":21717357,"value":""}, {"id":21728942,"value":null}, {"id":21732321,"value":"Test End-User"}], "satisfaction_rating":null }';

var obj = JSON.parse(json);
$('body').append('<div>Tags value: ' + obj.tags + '</div><br>');
var len = obj.custom_fields.length;

for(n = 0; n < len; n++)
{
    $('body').append('<div>Custom field value: ' + obj.custom_fields[n].value + '</div>');
}
```

​

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/7nbpq/5/

Comment: Ok, I will give this a go...but the 'tickets' contains various individual tickets...so that JSON code I posted...that is only one ticket. How do I specify which ticket within that object I want to deal with? Basically I am asking how to do array[2] for the JSON object

Comment: You'd have to loop through it, just as I do in my answer, except instead just use "var len = obj.length;" and then in your loop, obj[n].tags or whatever you want to access.

Comment: I tried this http://jsfiddle.net/7nbpq/5/ (thanks for linking to jsfiddle, I never heard of it before but it should make testing easier :)) But it doesn't display anything. Basically I just wanted to see what the length is for the whole object, there are 6 tickets in it so I would like to see a return value of 6 but I get nothing...

Comment: Yea, I forgot the object wouldn't work with length. Try this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/7nbpq/10/

Comment: Ok that looks good but what about when there is another level...so multiple tickets within the tickets?? So the actual JSON in that case is like this http://jsfiddle.net/7nbpq/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try using json_encode() on your server side return, and/or jQuery.parseJSON() on your client side reception of data. This should allow you to get the data in an array which would help a ton.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use $.getJSON - it's a [shorthand for $.ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), specifically for retrieving JSON:

```
$.getJSON('myfile.json', function(json) {

    // do something with json here 
});
```

Secondly, once you have the json, you can access it with dot operators - there's no need to parse it, since it already is an object.

Comment: If that's the case, it has nothing to do with $.getJSON - it's a shorthand to $.ajax. Exactly what problems are you running into?

Comment: Please see the link above to try it out or here:  http://www.sanbarcomputing.com/flat/forumPosts/getJSON/getJSON.html Thanks.  I get the following error in the Chrome console:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : I had this problem before, and seem to remember it is interpreting it as JavaScript code.

Comment: It seems to be a JSON vs. JSONP problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you with your JSON retrieval and accessing the resultant object

Try it out [**here**](http://www.quirkscode.com/flat/forumPosts/src/getJSON/getJSON.html)  View the console.log() output with the console (press F12 in Chrome, or use FireBug in FireFox, etc):

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $.getJSON("getJSON.json", function (data) {
        $("#look").on('click', function () {
            var $output = $("#output");
            var index, id = $("#input").val();
            var filtered = data.custom_fields.filter(function (element) {
                return element.id.toString() == id;
            });
            $output.empty();
            for (index in filtered) {
                $output.append("Value: " + filtered[index].value);
            }
            console.log(filtered);
        });
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Pleased input a custom field ID:  <input id="input" type="text" value="21732321" />
    <button id="look">Look Up By ID</button>
    <p id="output"></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="getJSON.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON (this is your JSON validated and formatted [**here**](http://jsonlint.com/)):

```
{
    "url": "https://test.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/6.json",
    "id": 6,
    "external_id": null,
    "via": {
        "channel": "web",
        "source": {
            "from": {},
            "to": {},
            "rel": null
        }
    },
    "created_at": "2012-10-02T21:14:59Z",
    "updated_at": "2012-10-09T18:22:04Z",
    "type": "incident",
    "subject": "Test Ticket",
    "description": "this is a test ticket",
    "priority": "normal",
    "status": "closed",
    "recipient": null,
    "requester_id": 271853958,
    "submitter_id": 271853958,
    "assignee_id": 270249903,
    "organization_id": 22284363,
    "group_id": 20363013,
    "collaborator_ids": [],
    "forum_topic_id": null,
    "problem_id": null,
    "has_incidents": false,
    "due_at": null,
    "tags": [
        "2_2_2",
        "arcb",
        "end_user_1",
        "var_2"
    ],
    "fields": [
        {
            "id": 21704983,
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 21708732,
            "value": "tried this"
        },
        {
            "id": 21708742,
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 21713331,
            "value": "10/2/2012"
        },
        {
            "id": 21717086,
            "value": "arcb"
        },
        {
            "id": 21717236,
            "value": "10/2/2012"
        },
        {
            "id": 21717357,
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 21728942,
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": 21732321,
            "value": "Test End-User"
        }
    ],
    "custom_fields": [
        {
            "id": 21704983,
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 21708732,
            "value": "tried this"
        },
        {
            "id": 21708742,
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 21713331,
            "value": "10/2/2012"
        },
        {
            "id": 21717086,
            "value": "arcb"
        },
        {
            "id": 21717236,
            "value": "10/2/2012"
        },
        {
            "id": 21717357,
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 21728942,
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": 21732321,
            "value": "Test End-User"
        }
    ],
    "satisfaction_rating": null
}
```